# Loop through attributes but only output certain ones - javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, attributes

I dont know much of js but I have a code that with a little modification, will do exactly what I want. So here is a part of it that Im stuck. I have some visual objects that have several attributes, most of these attributes are needed for drawing them on the map so I cant just `comment` them out. I also have a function that prints all the attributes of the object `on("mouseover")`. I want it to only display the attributes I want, not all.

```
.on("mouseover", function(d) {
    var out = "";
    out += d.name + "<br /><br />";
    for (v in d) {
      out += (!Number.isNaN(Number(d[v])) ? v + ": " + Number(d[v]) + "<br />" : "");
    }
    document.getElementById("detail").innerHTML = out;
  }
```

I understand what this code does, but what is the most elegant way to constraint the `for` loop or the `out` to only include the attributes I want?

The current outcome

```
obj name

attrIwant1: value
attrIwant2: value
attrIwant3: value
attrIwant4: value
w: blah
x: blah
y: blah
z: blah
```

I only want to display up until `w:blah`.

Comment: Without a minimum working example for us to play with its hard to give an exact answer. You can store the fields you want in an array or other data structure and use a conditional statement in the loop to check against the property name and see if its in the array.

Comment: What attributes, of how many, do you want from which element(s)? Can you share your [mcve] code, and the actual desired output, in order that we can help you?

Comment: I already got the help from @dcp , as my example didnt need all that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the attributes you care about in a set, then when you loop, see if `d[v]` belongs to the set.

```
const set1 = new Set(['attrIWant1', 'attrIWant2']); // add the attributes here
for (v in d) {
  if (set1.has(d[v])) {
    // this is one we care about
  }
}
```

Read more about sets here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

Comment: it should be `if (set1.has(v))` , but yeah, this did it nicely. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you always expect the same number of attributes, you can terminate the loop early when `out` has a certain number of `<br />`'s in it.

In your example you want to stop when you have 4 attributes, so you would terminate the loop when `out` contains 6 `<br />`'s. Your new for loop would be this:

```
for (v in d) {
  out += (!Number.isNaN(Number(d[v])) ? v + ": " + Number(d[v]) + "<br />" : "");
  if (out.match(/<br \/>/g).length === 6) break;
}
```

It is not "elegant", but it's probably the best you'll get without telling me what `d` is :^)

Comment: this looks like a nifty solution as well!